# Jekyll paginate

Tags: pagination, jekyll

I am trying to paginate a list of blog posts in jekyll, but cant seem to get it working. Here's my setup
I have a blog directory under my root directory which has a index.md. I have used the following code from the jekyll website

```
<ul>
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
<li><h1><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I have the following in my _config.yml

```
paginate: 10
```

nothing get's displayed. Any suggestions as to where I am messing up?

Update - Dir structure

```
$ls
_config.yml _layouts    _site       css     index.html
_includes   _posts

$ cd blog
$ ls
index.md
```

Comment: Do you have files in your `_posts` directory?

Comment: Also make sure your [post filenames](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#the-posts-folder) follow the `YEAR-MONTH-DAY-title.MARKUP` convention.

Comment: Yup, already have both done.

Comment: Did you add a paginate path in your config? `paginate_path: "/blog/page:num/"`

Comment: `paginate_path` is mentioned in docs on enabling pagination: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/#enable-pagination

Comment: Send your code to github. Give us the repository url and we'll give you a good answer in five minutes.

Comment: I feel it might be due to the dir structure I have setup.. here is what I have
`$ ls` 
`_config.yml _layouts _site  css  index.html`
`_includes _posts  blog  img  js`

The ` index.html ` is a landing page, under the blog dir I have a index.md where I am trying to paginate the list of blog post (just a list not display or preview)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple solution: As written in the [jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/) you have to provide a `index.html` (even `blog.html` won't work).

So simply rename your `blog/index.md` to `blog/index.html` and having `paginate_path: "/blog/page:num/"` and `paginate: 10` set in your `_config.yml` you are fine.

Cheers...

Comment: In my case, I had to remove the permalink in the front-matter for it to work.

Comment: @Sentry.co what does this mean? can you please explain

Comment: Here is my config: https://github.com/sentryco/sentryco.github.io